# meaning of the word "guess" in contex

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/SIOQgY1tqrU). It is at 14 minutes and 13 seconds.

> You better **guess** the folks at that Galaudet College went out and celebrate the rest of the day when somebody came up with that one.

I have got no idea what the lecturer is talking about because of that word. Help me please understand the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the context of the lecture, it's a bit of an odd choice to use the word **guess** in this sentence. He's trying to emphasize that the American Sign Language gesture for "pasteurized milk" is rather funny because it's literally symbolized as "past your eyes milk." A better choice of word, and what I would surmise he was likely going for, could be

> "You'd better **believe** the folks at that Galaudet College went out
>   and celebrated the rest of the day when somebody came up with that
>   one."

"You'd better believe..." is an idiom/expression used for telling someone that something is definitely true and that they should take it seriously. In this case, the lecturer is jokingly saying that the gesture looks ridiculous, but in fact, it is a real gesture that actually means "pasteurized milk".